# How to bend more than 90 degree?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a){test};
\node(b)[below=5cm of a]{test2};
\draw[red,bend right=90](b.east)to(a.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a simple question, I'm searching for a way to bend the line more than 90, ideally the line should make a bigger detour. How should I do it?

Here is what I mean: [image: Image of bending]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Option 1

You could change your `bend right=90` to `out=-45, in=45`.

[image]

### Option 2

You could use a Bezier curve. Adjust the `5` to the value you like.

```
\draw[red](b.east) .. controls +(5,0) and +(5,0) .. (a.east);
```

[image]

Comment: no sorry, that is not what I meant. I want the line to go more far away, in your example, to go east until it reaches your avatar.

Comment: please see the attached picture

Comment: This is it, but I can't see your code, only the picture

Comment: replace \draw[red](b.east) .. controls +(5,0) and +(5,0) .. (a.east);

Comment: in code given above by john

Answer (score 12):

Are you looking for the `looseness` Option?

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(a){test};
  \node(b)[below=5cm of a]{test2};
  \draw[red,bend right=90,
    looseness=3
  ](b.east)to(a.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with

```
\draw[red,out=-20, in=20,
  looseness=3
](b.east)to(a.east);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use `distance`:

```
\draw[red](b.east)to[bend right=90,distance=7cm](a.east);
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a){test};
\node(b)[below=5cm of a]{test2};
\draw[red](b.east)to[bend right=90,distance=7cm](a.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can put the `controls` straight in the options of `to` operation.

```
\draw[red](b.east)to[controls=+(0:7) and +(0:7)](a.east);
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a){test};
\node(b)[below=5cm of a]{test2};
\draw[red](b.east)to[controls=+(0:7) and +(0:7)](a.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution using your style of "nodes"-
You can leave the node label empty to have only 2 nodes "visible".

You can change the `tension=1.5` to your liking.

You can find more information on control points and tension in `TikZ` manual on Section 2.4 on page 31.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(a){test};
\node(b)[below=5cm of a]{test2};
\node(c)[below right=3cm of a]{control node};
%\draw[red,bend right=90] (b.east) to (a.east);
\draw[red] plot [smooth, tension=1.5] coordinates {
    (b.east) (c.east) (a.east)
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the example with empty node

[image]